# PySimpleGUI invalid ASCII Character

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysimplegui

When trying to run a test a GUI to use with the ARK Taming Calculator I'm working on, GUI test gives me the error

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "GUItest.py", line 1, in 
import PySimpleGUI as sg
File "/home/nunya/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/**init**.py, line 2, in 
from .PySimpleGUI import  *
File "/home/nunya/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySimpleGUI.py', line 523
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /home/nunya/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySimpleGUI.py on line 523, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details**

Looking at the site it provides, I don't under stand what it was stating, and havent been able to figure out what is wrong with PySimpleGUI.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (under "Python Versions"):

> As of 9/25/2018 both Python 3 and Python 2.7 are supported when using `tkinter` version of `PySimpleGUI`! The Python 3 version is named `PySimpleGUI`. The Python 2.7 version is `PySimpleGUI27`.

So you should substitute `PySimpleGUI` with `PySimpleGUI27` (or switch to Python 3).

Comment: Ok, thanks, now to figure how to change Geany to python 3.